# shortcut to .exe created by .bat file doesn't work

Tags: batch-file, exe, shortcut

this is the content of the batch file:

```
@echo off

set SCRIPT="script.vbs"

echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >> %SCRIPT%
echo sLinkFile = "%~dp0Block Dodger.lnk" >> %SCRIPT%
echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile) >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.TargetPath = "%~dp0Block Dodger files\Block_Dodger.exe" >> %SCRIPT%
echo oLink.Save >> %SCRIPT%

cscript /nologo %SCRIPT%
del %SCRIPT%
```

when i run this it does create a correct shortcut to the game.exe but when i start the shortcut i get the following error:

[shortcut error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibMkD.png)

the actual game.exe itself works perfectly fine, even when i manually create a shortcut it works, i dont know why the shortcut created by the batch file doesn't work.
how do i fix this?

edit: i dont know if it would matter but the folder Block Dodger files contains other files too that the .exe needs to run, i dont know if these should all be included in the batch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd have probably done it like this, ensuring that the target path is doublequoted, to protect the space characters:

```sh
@(  Echo Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
    Echo Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)
    Echo sLinkFile = "%~dp0Block Dodger.lnk"
    Echo Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile^)
    Echo oLink.TargetPath = """%~dp0Block Dodger files\Block_Dodger.exe"""
    Echo oLink.WorkingDirectory = "%~dp0Block Dodger files"
    Echo oLink.Save
    Echo oFS.DeleteFile WScript.ScriptFullName) >"script.vbs"
@%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe /NoLogo "script.vbs"
```

Other than doublequoting the target path, the only real change is that I'm asking the VBScript to self destruct, instead of deleting it afterwards with `@Del "script.vbs"`. *(You can reinstate that as a new last line, and delete `Echo Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"^)`, and `Echo oFS.DeleteFile WScript.ScriptFullName`, if you prefer.)* Based upon your comment, I've now included an additional property, because the shortcut did not have the **Start in:** location propagated.

Comment: it still doesnt work, that might be because in the block dodger files folder there are a lot of .pyd and .dll files aswell that block dodger.exe needs to run. should all these files be included in the batch file, and if so, how would i do that?

Comment: That's not the fault of the code above @Bjorn, it's just missing a property you didn't provide in your question. I've now added that missing property to my answer above, please retry.

Answer (score 0):

i ended up fixing it in a different way.

imporvised shortcut:

```
start /d "%~dp0Block Dodger files" Block_Dodger.exe
```